# Как лучше округлить полученное число?

Tags: python, числа, округление

Число к примеру 1 526, нужно округлить до 2000.
Собираю число с вэб элемента:

```
tab_int = int(re.findall(r'\d+', tab_metric)[0])
```

И ещё я правильно понимаю, что в итоге я собираю из 1526 только 1?
Я не собираю одно число потому, что веб элемент может быть таким: «1.4 млн»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно задать такую регулярку для поиска чисел

Попробуйте:

```
import re

tab_metric = ' 1 526 '

# Если ее размерность может быть неопределенной, тогда больше подойдет такое: r'\d+(?: \d+)*'
tab_str = re.findall(r'\d+ \d+', tab_metric)[0]

# Пробел для тысячных не совсем пробел:
print(tab_str, repr(tab_str))
# 1 526 '1\u2009526'

tab_int = int(re.sub(r'\D', '', tab_str))
print(tab_int)
# 1526
```

Встроенная функция [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) [может округлить через задание отрицательных значений](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46481370/5909792):

```
print(round(tab_int, -3))
# 2000
```

---

**PS.**

Символ `\u2009` это [THIN SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm)